# Button or link to toggle length of multiple lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, list, toggle

I have lists of checkboxes as filters. Some of these lists however, are too long. I would like to be able to toggle them to a specified length or full length for user experience.
I've managed to make it work like this, but the problem is that with this method, clicking on the link will toggle all list rather than just the one. So i need to make it work for each list seperately.

---

### In my controller:

```
$scope.limit = 5;
$scope.isShowMore = true;

$scope.showMore = function() {

    $scope.limit = $scope.length;
    $scope.isShowMore = false;
};

$scope.showLess = function() {

    $scope.limit = 5;
    $scope.isShowMore = true;
}
```

---

### In my view:

```
<ul>
 <h4>By Country</h4>
 <li ng-repeat="country in countries | limitTo:limit">
  <div class="form-check">
   <label class="form-check-label">
    <input style="vertical-align:middle;position:relative;bottom:3px;" ng-model="filter.country[country]" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="{{country}}">{{country | capitalise}}
   </label>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
<a href="javascript:;" ng-click="showMore()" ng-show="isShowMore">... Show More</a><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="showLess()" ng-hide="isShowMore">... Show Less </a>
```

### [image]

I'm thinking that I should move this out of my controller into a directive, but don't know if this is correct or how to do so. I'm new to AngularJS, please help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's better to have a custom directive for which I've already made which you can use like below if in case in future if you want to use multiple check boxes and need to collect what all items are collected you can use a custom directive.Here is a [link](https://ngcoderscope.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/multi-checkbox-directive/) on how to use it.

Below is sample code snippet in HTML

```
<body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <h1>Multi Check box</h1>
 <multi-checkbox selectedlist="req.selectedList" orginallist="req.sourceList" value="code" label="desc" all="true" sort-by="desc"></multi-checkbox>
 <pre ng-cloak>{{req.selectedList |json}}</pre>
</body>
```

This requires a source list(orginallist) and a destination list(selectedlist) where selected values should go,it also sorts the list as per your need.

Just add this directive in your JS file and you can use this directive anywhere anytime, it's a one time activity.So I hope this helps you.

```
mainApp.directive('multiCheckbox', ['$log', '$filter', '$timeout', function($log, $filter, $timeout) {

    return {

        restrict: 'EA',//E-element & A - attribute

        template:

            '<div> <div ng-show="checkbox.showAll" class="checkbox"> ' +

            '<label style="font-size: 12px"> <input type="checkbox" ' +

            'id="all" name="all" ng-model="checkbox.all" ' +

            'ng-checked="checkbox.all" ng-change="selectAll()" /> All ' +

            '</label> ' +

            '</div>' +

            '<div ng-repeat="item in list  track by $index "class="checkbox"> ' +

            '<label style="font-size: 12px"> <input type="checkbox" ' +

            'id="{{item.value}}" name="{{item.label}}"  ' +

            'ng-checked="item.checked" ng-click="$parent.toggle($index)"/> {{item.label}}' +

            '</label>' +

            '</div> </div>',

        replace: true,  //to replace our custom template in place of tag <multi-checkbox>

        transclude: false,//make it true if we want to insert anything  btw directive tags

        scope: {  //isolate scope created 

            selectedlist: '=',

            orginallist: '=',

            value: '@',

            label: '@',

            all: '@',

            sortBy: '@'

        },

        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

            $scope.checkbox = {};

            $scope.checkbox.all = false; //set 'All' checkbox to false

            $scope.checkbox.showAll = $scope.all == 'true' ? true : false;//to show/hide 'All' checkbox

            //function called on click of check box
            $scope.toggle = function(index) {

                var item = $scope.list[index];

                var i = $scope.selectedlist.length > 0 ? $scope.selectedlist.indexOf(item.value) : -1;

                item.checked = !item.checked;

                if (!item.checked) {

                    $scope.selectedlist.splice(i, 1);//remove item if unchecked

                    $scope.checkbox.all = false;//make 'All' to uncheck too

                } else if (item.checked) {

                    $scope.selectedlist.push(item.value);//add item if checked

                }

            };

            //function called when 'All' checkbox is checked
            $scope.selectAll = function() {

                var totalList = $scope.list;

                $scope.selectedlist = [];

                //if selected add all items 
                //if unchecked remove all items from selected list
                angular.forEach(totalList, function(item) {

                    item.checked = $scope.checkbox.all;

                    if (item.checked) {

                        $scope.selectedlist.push(item.value);

                    } else {

                        $scope.selectedlist = [];

                    }

                });

            };


            //always watch my source list if it has been modified and update back..
            $scope.$watch('orginallist', function(value) {

                //sort accordingly..
                value = $filter('orderBy')(value, $scope.sortBy);

                $scope.list = [];

                if (angular.isArray(value)) {

                    angular.forEach(value, function(item) {

                        $scope.list.push({

                            value: item[$scope.value],

                            label: item[$scope.label],

                            checked: item.checked

                        });

                    });

                }

            }, true);


            //clear 'All' checkbox value if all items are de selected
            $scope.$watch('selectedlist', function(value) {

                if (!angular.isArray(value) || (angular.isArray(value) && value.length <= 0)) {

                    $scope.checkbox.all = false;

                }

            }, true);
        }

    };

}]);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late repsonse, sometimes it's hard to find spare time... This works perfectly. Thank you very much for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive which will add `show more` and `show less` links after  the `ul` element and initialize based on the values you pass to the directive. Check out this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrpruthvi/255coczp/)**.

**Directive:**

```
MyApp.directive("showMoreLess", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    replace: false,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      min: "@minValue",
      max: "=maxValue"
    },
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude><a href="" ng-click="showMore()" ng-show="!isShowMore">... Show More</a><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="showLess()" ng-show="isShowMore">... Show Less </a>',
    link: function(scope, ele, attr) {
      scope.limit = parseInt(scope.min);
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.showMore = function() {
        $scope.limit = parseInt($scope.max);
        $scope.isShowMore = true;
      };
      $scope.showLess = function() {
        $scope.limit = parseInt($scope.min);
        $scope.isShowMore = false;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

**Template:**

```
<ul show-more-less min-value="3" max-value="countries.length">
   <h4>By Country</h4>
   <li ng-repeat="country in countries | limitTo:$parent.limit"><!-- Note that we are using $parent.limit since transclude child elements don't have access to transclude element scope -->
    ...
   </li>
<ul>
```

- **min-value:** Initial limits list to this number
- **max-value:** Max number of list items to be displayed

***Note:*** We are using `$parent.limit` in filter since transclude child elements don't have access to transclude element scope.